# A div is Overlapping fixed bar HTML CSS Jquery

Tags: jquery, html, css, overlap

[image]

I have a fixed header consisting of banner and a menu system and i have a timeline content which changes dynamically.. however on scrolling the dynamic content starts overlapping the fixed one ... which breaks  my page !! ...

Comment: Is the "main content" inside a wrapper? If not, place into one and set `top:` to the height of the header.

Answer (score 0):

Please share your code. 
But I am guessing that you could set the "Overflow" property on the container of dynamic content to "Hidden"

[Overflow property](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_overflow.asp)